# VPN not setting correct DNS server

Tags: dns, vpn, resolv.conf

I set my VPN connection to explicitly use 192.168.253.65 server but my Ubuntu (19.04) does not do that. It tries to resolves servers from other IP addresses and fails to do so. 
The /etc/resolv.conf gets filled up with other servers I do not know.

My ubuntu 18.04 LTS seems to have behaved differently. Would you have any ideas? What to try? What could be a problem? THanks.

[image]

**Update:**

- the one that behaves correctly was Ubuntu 18.04LTS
- 19.04 Ubuntu gave me the above problems.

On both of them I used network manager and I have configured it the same way for SSTP VPN.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp
sudo apt-get install sstp-client
```

When connecting on UBUNTU 19.04 (problems) - I saw that DNS showed some errors? / and it used limited feature set (DNS). I think this might be somehow related to resolving DNS.

Comment: could we have a little more context? where else do you do something like this? on a windows? what steps did you take there for it to work?

Comment: Also, which VPN are you using and which instructions did you use to set it up? You said your 18.04 behaved differently? Which version are you having the problem on? Could you post your ifconfig info too please? May help.

Comment: Hi @tatsu. thanks for message. I gave some more info. Still investigating the problems. The issues where between two differentr version of ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @jwcooper. thanks for message. I gave some more info. The ifconfigs and routes looked very similar.

Comment: Could you please post the errors that DNS showed? If you're 100% sure that everything is identical between your 18.04 and 19.04 installs, then it could just be that they've changed something that is no longer compatible with the sstp-client library. In that case, we just need to find out what it doesnt like and change it. Also, what are the addresses that it is putting in the /etc/resolv.conf file?